# Difference results assigning a variable within a function, and calling a function from a function in R

Tags: r

I'm struggling to understand the source of difference in these outputs for a function I wrote that lengthens a vector to a desired length. In the first instance of the function I used variable assignment for `current_length <- length(x)`:

```
lengthen_vector <- function(x, target_length){
  repeat{
    current_length <- length(x)
    x <- append(x, current_length + 1, after = current_length)
    current_length <- current_length + 1
      if(current_length == target_length) {
        return(x)
        break
      }
    }
  }
```

Which results as expected for a target length of 20 from a starting length of 10:

`[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20`

However, when I change from variable assignment to calling the length() function throughout the vector_lengthen() function as shown below:

```
lengthen_vector <- function(x, target_length){
  repeat{
    x <- append(x, length(x) + 1, after = length(x))
    length(x) <- length(x) + 1
      if(length(x) == target_length) {
        return(x)
        break
      }
    }
  }
```

...results in the following:

`[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 NA 13 NA 15 NA 17 NA 19 NA`

What is the difference between these two that is causing this? I can't seem to locate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning of `length(x) <- n` is to make the length of x to be n by either cutting it off or extending it with NAs.  For example,

```
x <- 1:3
length(x) <- 4
x
## [1]  1  2  3 NA
```

so if in your second version `x` has 10 elements then after the first `append` is performed `x` will have 11 elements and then the `length(x) <- length(x) + 1` will extend it to 12 elements by appending an NA.

Just omit the `length(x) <- length(x) + 1` statement giving:

```
lengthen_vector1 <- function(x, target_length){
  repeat{
    x <- append(x, length(x) + 1, after = length(x))
      if(length(x) == target_length) {
        return(x)
        break
      }
    }
  }
```

There are still some additional improvements that can be made:

- remove the `break` statement since it can never be reached given that it comes after a `return` statement.  Alternately move the `return` statement to after the loop.
- if the `target_length` is less than or equal to the length of `x` it will loop forever. This leaves open what it should do in that case. Let us assume that if the `target_length` is less than the length of `x` that we should return `x` unchanged.  To do these items place the `if` statement before the `append` statement and fix the `if` so that it returns unless the `target_length` exceeds the length of `x`.  Also, if that is done then the `if` and `repeat` can be consolidated into a `while` statement.
- since the extra numbers are added to the end of `x` we can use `c` instead of `append` avoiding the third argument.

Thus we can write:

```
lengthen_vector2 <- function(x, target_length) {
  while(length(x) < target_length) {
    x <- c(x, length(x) + 1)
  }
  x
}

lengthen_vector2(1:10, 15)
##  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15

lengthen_vector2(1:10, 3)
## [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Also it could be done without loops by concatenating the required sequence to the end of `x`.  We specify that the sequence ends in `target_length` and the length of the sequence is `target_length - length(x)` or 0 if negative.

```
lengthen_vector3 <- function(x, target_length) {
  c(x, seq(to = target_length, length = max(target_length - length(x), 0)))
}
```

If we wanted to be able to shrink the length as well as expand it then call `length_vector3` using `head(x, target_length)` instead of `x`.

```
lengthen_vector4 <- function(x, target_length) {
  lengthen_vector3(head(x, target_length), target_length)
}

lengthen_vector4(1:10, 15)
##  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15

lengthen_vector4(1:10, 3)
## [1]  1  2  3
```

or combine the last two into a single function:

```
lengthen_vector5 <- function(x, target_length) {
  c(head(x, target_length), 
    seq(to = target_length, length = max(target_length - length(x), 0)))
}
```